# Tooltip onmouseover event of a custom button in Kendo?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-angular2

I create a Kendo grid edit button like so:

```
command: [{
    name: "MyEdit",
    click: myFunc,
    template: "<a id= 'myEdit' class='k-grid-MyEdit k-button'><span class='k-icon k-i-edit'></span></a>"
}]
```

My requirement is when I hover on the button, a kendo tooltip should show up. Since kendo command custom button does not have a built-in `onmouseover` or `onhover` event, I found the following solution to trigger `onmouseover` event:

```
$(grid.element).on("mouseover mouseenter", ".k-grid-MyEdit", function(e) {
   alert("Hello"); //this works   
   //implement tooltip here
});
```

I tried implementing a kendo tooltip but was not able to destroy it. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to implement your own tooltip mechanism: you can directly use [Kendo UI tooltip](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip).

To add a tooltip to your button, you add the following declaration:

```
$(grid.element).kendoTooltip({
    filter: ".k-grid-MyEdit",
    width: 120,
    position: "top", 
    content: 'My tooltip'
});
```

Here how it works:

- you create a `kendoTooltip` on the element that contains whatever elements you want to display on tooltip on (here, your grid)
- the [`filter`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip/configuration/filter) attribute is a selector: the tooltip will show on all the children elements that match the selector (so here, your buttons)
- the [`content`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tooltip/configuration/content) attribute is what you want to display in your tooltip (it can also be a template)

I've created a jsFiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/7ue2zq45/1/

Comment: Nice answer. Just a tip: As the tooltip is being defined for a many elements, you don't know the what shoud be in `content` at the widget initialization. But if the target element(the `a` tag in this case) has an `data-title` attribute, the tooltip will use the attribute value in it's content.